# Why is GDB changing what is in the given address?

Tags: gdb

I am running a really simple program with a variable called `vars` which is an integer array, the base of this array is `0x555555558080`.

I have

```c
vars[0] = 0x00004444;
vars[1] = 0x12345678;
```

Then running gdb I get this:

```
(gdb) x/2xw 0x555555558080
0x555555558080 <vars>:  0x00004444      0x12345678

(gdb) x/4xh 0x555555558080
0x555555558080 <vars>:  0x4444  0x0000  0x5678  0x1234

(gdb) x/8xb 0x555555558080
0x555555558080 <vars>:  0x44    0x44    0x00    0x00    0x78    0x56    0x34    0x12
```

What actually doesn't make sense to me. The first output tells me that at the address `0x555555558080` the first byte I have is `0x00`, the other two outputs give me `0x44` as the first byte. If I really read the value at the given address, what will really be there? `0x44` or `0x00`?

What I had as first thought is the little-endian stuff, so at address `0x555555558084 (vars + 4)` I would have `0x78563412` before the conversion, but the outputs are not consistent with this, the first gives me the real value `0x12345678`, the second `0x5678 0x1234` which I expected to be `0x1234 0x5678`, the third output is the little-endian version.

I expected it to be:

```
(gdb) x/2xw 0x555555558080
0x555555558080 <vars>:  0x00004444      0x12345678

(gdb) x/4xh 0x555555558080
0x555555558080 <vars>:  0x0000  0x4444  0x1234  0x5678

(gdb) x/8xb 0x555555558080
0x555555558080 <vars>:  0x00    0x00    0x44    0x44    0x12    0x34    0x56    0x78
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I had as first thought is the little-endian stuff

It *is* exactly little endian stuff.

The actual stored bytes are: `0x44 0x44 0x00 0x00 0x78 0x56 0x34 0x12`. The rest is how you *interpret* them.

If you interpret them as two 32-bit ints, you get `0x00004444 0x12345678`.
If you interpret them as four 16-bit ints, you get `0x4444 0x0000 0x5678 0x1234`.

Everything here matches little-endian computer.

> I expected it to be:
>   `(gdb) x/4xh 0x555555558080
>   0x555555558080 <vars>:  0x0000  0x4444  0x1234  0x5678`

Well, your expectation is wrong. When you are looking at the first two bytes, they are `0x44 0x44`, so you can't expect to get `0x0000` from them.